# How do I use cloud functions with an angular fire project?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Ive deployed my angular app using @angular/fire but I can't find where to build my cloud functions with angular firebase, normally under a regular firebase project I would write them in the index.ts in the functions folder, but there is no function folder or index.ts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions are deployed the same way, no matter what frontend platform or framework you're using.  Typically you would not mix your frontend and backend code, and instead keep them in separate spaces.  Just `firebase init` in a new folder and manage the code from there.